# php. почему отправленные формой картинки на сервер, браузер не видит?

Tags: php

сделал форму для добавления статтей на сайт, с картинками, только проблема, переданые методом POST картинки как буд то заколдованы, не отображаются на сайте, хотя в папках сервера все норм, картинки на месте с другими картинками. И картинки сервер у себя в папке нормально отображает, а браузер их не видит

```
 <form action='edit.php' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type='text' size='10' name='category' value='Category'><br><br>
  <input type='text' size='100' name='title' value='Title'><br><br>
  <input type='text' size='140' name='link' value='Galary'><br><br>
  <input type='text' size='140' name='description' value='Description'><br><br>
  <input type="file" name="file_name" >
  <p class="p">Input Content</p>
  <textarea name='content' cols='105' rows='20'><img src="../images/img.jpg" align="left"  vspace="5" hspace="5" ></textarea><br>
  <button name="enter"><p>Enter</p></button><br>
```

код php :

```
if (isset($_FILES['file_name'])) {

$name =  $_FILES['file_name']['name'];

if ($_FILES['file_name']['error'] == 0 && $_FILES['file_name']['size'] > 0) {

$path = 'images/ ';

if (@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'], $path.$name)) {
echo 'Файл загружен';
}
else {
echo 'Ошибка при загрузке';
}
```

Comment: что значит "браузер их не видит"? Как вы пытаетесь их "увидеть" в браузере?

Comment: заходишь на сайт, а там статьи с картинками....картинки которые были добавлены прямо на мой хостинг хостинг - отображаются,  а картинки которые были переданы в ту же папку методом POST (вместе с текстовыми полями) не отображаются на сайте(отображается только текст, а вместо картинки значок). Хотя все пути  к картинке прописаны нормально и имена картинок совпадают...если в браузере открыть код страницы и нажать ссылку картинки, то  сообщается что файл ненайден. хотя как говорилось все картинки на месте в папке

Comment: т.е. у вас есть две картинки: картинка `a.png` залита ручками на сервер, картинка `b.png` залита через вашу форму. При этом если открыть в браузере картинку `a.png` (т.е. перейти по адресу http://ваш-сайт/images/a.png) - она открывается. Если сделать то же самое с картинкой `b.png` (перейти по адресу http://ваш-сайт/images/b.png) - картинка уже не открывается. В этом проблема? А попробуйте плохой файл переименовать - тогда открывается? и с расширением не ошиблись? Было бы лучше, если бы вы реальные адреса картинок привели (или хотя бы домен, например, test.ru указать) Вообще похоже на опечатку

Comment: да! если вручную его переименовать (только имя)- то работает , ниче не меняя в коде и тегах , почему то  ...

Comment: И еще бы желательно посмотреть какие права у этих файлов. Хостинг кстати какой? Стандартный shared или сами настраивали?

Comment: хостинг webspace а сайт http://ivarious.com, в настройки хостина (php настройки) я пока не лез , так как там ниче не смыслю,

Comment: @newman, так он же сам эти файлы пишет, т.е. права быть должны. Автор - а имя файла какое? Там есть русские символы? Или может имя файла очень большое? Вы пример приведите, так нагляднее будет

Comment: все именя английскими...если загруженый файл перейменовать то все норм отображается, значит при пересылке методом POST там какие то  действия на имени происходят

Comment: @BOPOH если один файл залит через ФТП, а другой через форму - то у них могут быть разные владельцы и разные права. Возможно и в этом дело.

Comment: если смотреть на права, которые показывает хостинг - то все одинаковы для всех картинок  -rw-r--r--

Comment: @newman, если бы не отображались файлы, загруженные по фтп - я бы понял, но не отображаются те файлы, которые были залиты апачем, т.е. в правах дело быть не может (только если что-то не меняет права файлов специально)

Comment: даже если картинку переименовать в то же самое имя - она начинает отображатся, а без переименования не отображается